WooCommerce Custom Payment Gateway Plugin Not Displaying in Checkout
I have created a custom payment gateway plugin for WooCommerce. The plugin activates without any errors, and debugging logs show that the gateway class is registered and initialized. However, the payment method does not appear in the WooCommerce checkout page, and the message "There are no payment methods available" is displayed.
Here's the complete code for the plugin:
<?php
/**
 * Plugin name: Noob Payment for Woocommerce
 * Plugin URI: http://www.insafinhaam.com/custom-woocommerce-payment-gateway-plugin
 * Author: Insaf Inhaam
 * Author URI: https://insafinhaam.com/
 * Description: This Plugin allows for local content payment system
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * License: 0.1.0
 * Text Domain: noob-pay-woo
 */

if (!in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins'))))
    return;

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'noob_payment_init', 11);

function noob_payment_init()
{
    if (class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) {
        class WC_Noob_pay_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->id = 'noob_payment';
                $this->icon = apply_filters('woocommerce_noob_icon', plugins_url('/assets/icon.png', __FILE__));
                $this->has_fields = false;
                $this->method_title = __('Noob Payment', 'noob-pay-woo');
                $this->method_description = __('Noob local content payment systems.', 'noob-pay-woo');

                $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
                $this->description = $this->get_option('description');
                $this->instructions = $this->get_option('instructions', $this->description);

                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();

                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
                // add_action( 'woocommerce_thank_you_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'thank_you_page' ) );
            }

            public function init_form_fields()
            {
                $this->form_fields = apply_filters('woo_noob_pay_fields', array(
                    'enabled' => array(
                        'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => __('Enable or Disable Noob Payments', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'default' => 'no'
                    ),
                    'title' => array(
                        'title' => __('Noob Payments Gateway', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'default' => __('Noob Payments Gateway', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __('Add a new title for the Noob Payments Gateway that customers will see when they are in the checkout page.', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    'description' => array(
                        'title' => __('Noob Payments Gateway Description', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'default' => __('Please remit your payment to the shop to allow for the delivery to be made', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __('Add a new title for the Noob Payments Gateway that customers will see when they are in the checkout page.', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    'instructions' => array(
                        'title' => __('Instructions', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'default' => __('Default instructions', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __('Instructions that will be added to the thank you page and odrer email', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    // 'enable_for_virtual' => array(
                    //     'title'   => __( 'Accept for virtual orders', 'woocommerce' ),
                    //     'label'   => __( 'Accept COD if the order is virtual', 'woocommerce' ),
                    //     'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    //     'default' => 'yes',
                    // ),
                )
                );
            }

            public function process_payments($order_id)
            {

                $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

                $order->update_status('on-hold', __('Awaiting Noob Payment', 'noob-pay-woo'));

                // if ( $order->get_total() > 0 ) {
                // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the cheque).
                // } else {
                // $order->payment_complete();
                // }

                // $this->clear_payment_with_api();

                $order->reduce_order_stock();

                WC()->cart->empty_cart();

                return array(
                    'result' => 'success',
                    'redirect' => $this->get_return_url($order),
                );
            }

            // public function clear_payment_with_api() {

            // }

            public function thank_you_page()
            {
                if ($this->instructions) {
                    echo wpautop($this->instructions);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_to_woo_noob_payment_gateway');

function add_to_woo_noob_payment_gateway($gateways)
{
    $gateways[] = 'WC_Noob_pay_Gateway';
    return $gateways;
}

What I have tried:

Confirmed that WooCommerce is active.

Verified that the plugin activates without any errors.

Checked the WordPress debug log, which shows that the WC_Simple_Noob_Pay_Gateway class is registered and initialized.


Expected Result:
The "Noob Payment" method should appear as a payment option on the WooCommerce checkout page.
Actual Result:
The checkout page displays the message: "There are no payment methods available. This may be an error on our side. Please contact us if you need any help placing your order."


Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i tried your code on a basic installation with woocommerce and the payement method appears directly in the checkout. maybe there is another plugin or theme which interfere ?
